# Is there a Windows 64-bit alternative to Wolfgang Schulter's WMF2EPS utility?

Tags: windows, postscript

For many years I used Wolfgang Schulter's WMF2EPS Postscript driver to programmatically convert WMF/EMF (Windows/Enhanced Metafiles) to EPS (Encapsulated Postscript).  My suite of programs and scripts generated EMF files, then invoked the `wmf2eps` command line program to convert the files, one at a time, to EPS.

I was recently forced to upgrade my production system from 32- to 64-bit Windows.  As a result, WMF2EPS no longer works, and I am unable to install the 32-bit printer driver to get things working.

Is there a viable alternative to WMF2EPS for 64-bit Windows?  I'm specifically looking for a similar programmatic solution which can be called from a program or script.

Here are some references related to WMF2EPS:

- [The (now-defunct) WMF2EPS Homepage](ftp://shamash.lpi.ac-poitiers.fr/pub/postcript/wmf2eps.htm)

  - This is an FTP-downloadable HTML page, last updated in 2000
- [The WMP2EPS homepage with Vista-related information (2009)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407173009/http://www.wolf-s.homepage.t-online.de/wmf2eps/vista.htm)

  - From the Internet Archives, I was not sure if the solution would work for Windows 10
- WMF2EPSC.EXE

  - There seems to be an improved WMF2EPS for 64-bit Windows called "WMF2EPSC", but I have not been able to locate information about it.

So the question is: is there a 64-bit version of WMF2EPS, or is there a viable programmatic alternative?

Comment: If you understand Japanese (I don't): https://yuu.nkjmlab.org/diary/20100409.html The heading of this looks promising.

Comment: This question is not clearly on topic here, imagemagic says it handles emf on windows but not sure if that includes 64bit http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/formats.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ImageMagick is AFIK still only vector2raster2vector destroying any benefit the WMF2EPS is native vector 2PS print 2 EPS file thus stays true vector problem is the PS print driver is difficult since PS5 is not free nor working with Win10

Comment: I got this CTAN https://ctan.org/pkg/wmf2eps package working by using a free PDF driver (similar to the virtual drivers in TeX) however it has to hook the Adobe PS5 dynamic link layer which Adobe previously made "freely available" but now seems to be difficult to source as this is like many older ctan packages now abandonware and thus only usable for the trial period it seems pointless to proceed The need for conversion from WMF2EPS is now fairly rare and the format MS specific thus this project was doomed from the outset

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Regarding the question being off-topic: apologies for the apparent mismatch, but I posted here for two reasons. (1) The WMF2EPS web site mentioned how its product could help with "TeX/LaTeX for typesetting scientific/technical stuff under Windows".  (2) A search for "WMF2EPS" in this forum netted two posts.  With thanks to those who answered here, what StackExchange forum would you recommend I post to instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wmf

Comment: A TeX related Solution turned up today see my answer to importing powerpoint graphics Ignore the registry bit and skip to the end Initial test suggest it is a perfect replacement since the installer does all the necessary background driver configuration If that works just as well as the older CTAN solution above (which needs sourcing a compatible print driver) then upvotes greatly appreciated there. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492077/poor-includegraphics-quality-of-powerpoint-illustration